# O que é Jakarta EE?

Tags: java, java-ee

Só mudou a nomenclatura do JavaEE ou ocorrerão outras alterações significativas?

Terá compatibilidade com JavaEE 8-?

O JavaEE e o JakartaEE serão mantidos pela mesma comunidade?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**JCP** (Java Community Process  - https://www.jcp.org/) - é um grupo de padronização da Oracle composto por mais de 800 empresa que definem a tecnologia.

Lembrando que Java não é apenas uma linguagem, é uma plataforma composta de  especificações(documento que diz como deve ser o java),implementações ( que é o software, linguagem, jvm ...) e testes de compatibilidades( que garante que estes softwares podem ser implementados).

**Java EE** é uma conjunto grande varias especificações feita pela JCP, por exemplo JSP, JMS, Servlets são algumas das especificações que compõe o Java EE.

Ou seja, as empresas se reúnem para fazer as especificações, e depois cada uma desenvolve suas implementações.

Um outro exemplo é o Hibernate que é utilizado para mapeamento objeto relacional, que não existia especificação no Java EE, e posteriormente foi incluido no Java EE através da especificação JPA.

Ultimamente com o lançamento de novos produtos a Oracle havia deixado meio que de lado os investimento no Java EE, sendo que as especificações Java eram em sua maioria quase sempre iniciadas e lideradas pela Oracle. Ou seja, em determinado momento, a Oracle tinha outra prioridades e tinha decidido não continuar seus investimentos no Java EE, e cedeu todos os direitos das especificações do Java EE para a Eclipse Foundation, o que tornou possível a Eclipse Foundation dar continuidade a evolução do Java EE.

A Oracle cedeu todo o código da especificação Java EE para a Eclipse Foundation, mas o nome Java é uma marca registrada da Oracle, e não poderia ser utilizado pela Eclipse Foundation, por isso eles fizeram um estudo e renomearam para Jakarta EE e criaram uma comunidade/organização chamada EE4J - Eclipse Enterprise for Java (EE4J) https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j, que a responsável pela especificação Jakarta EE.

Logo nos primeiros passos da especificação do Jakarta EE 8 foi especificado que deveria ser mantida a compatibilidade com o Java 8.

Answer (score 11):

Jakarta EE é a plataforma de desenvolvimento para Java empresarial. Ela é gerenciada pela Eclipse. Eles mudaram o nome antigo, que era JavaEE, porque havia muito referências à plataforma, que será marca registrada da Oracle. A permissão para usar a marca registada “Jakarta EE” dependerá de um programa de compatibilidade, pelo qual as tecnologias candidatas têm de passar e ainda não foi desenvolvido. Ele será gerido pela EE.next.